# Using namespace for static class members

Tags: c++, namespaces

Can someone explain why the following code does not work? I cannot find any resources explaining the how namespaces, classes and identifiers fit together. When you do my_class::my_member, the my_class:: part is not a namespace? What is it?

```
#include <iostream>

class my_class {
    public:
            static void my_member() {
                    std::cout << "worked" << std::endl;
            }
};

int main() {

    using namespace my_class; // error: 'my_class' is not a namespace-name

    my_member(); // error: 'my_member' was not declared in this scope

    my_class::my_member(); // works
}
```

As a more general question: is there a way I can reference static class members without doing the my_class:: namespace/ identifier/ whatever each time?

Instead of

```
my_class::my_member_1
my_class::my_member_2
```

I just want

```
my_member_1
my_member_2
```

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: the compiler already explained : `error: 'my_class' is not a namespace-name`. Which part of it is not clear?

Comment: Not that it is legal, but why do you think you need to pull in symbols from the scope of my_class into the global namespace?

Comment: @BЈовић When you do my_class::my_member, the my_class:: part is not a namespace? What is it?

Comment: @thokra is there a way I can reference static class members without doing the my_class:: namespace/ identifier/ whatever each time?

Comment: my_class is class - not a namespace. You should get a good c++ book which explains basics of c++

Comment: @user2675345: do you actually need a class for your purpose? Do you only have static members?

Comment: @BЈовић You seem to be ignoring the rest of my question. If it is not a namespace then what is it and why does it act like a namespace is most situations? I shan't bother asking you to recommend a "good" C++ book since you clearly haven't read any yourself.

Comment: @thokra Yeah, I'm beginning to come to the conclusion that maybe I could use an actual namespace instead of a class. I guess I need to figure out which answer aptly states that what i want it not possible to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes, indirectly.  If you create a method that operates in `my_class`'s scope, then you can get the behavior you want.

```
#include <iostream>

class my_class {
    public:
            static void my_member() {
                    std::cout << "worked" << std::endl;
            }
            static int my_main();
};

int my_class::my_main() {

    my_member(); // no error

    my_class::my_member(); // works too
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main() {
     my_class::my_main();
}
```

Comment: How exactly is this supposed to compile? Calling my_class.my_main() requires an instance. Also, how does that spare the OP the work they are trying to avoid? This is much more writing to do to begin with.

Comment: @thokra, you're mistaken -- `my_main` is declared as `static` and thus does not require an instance.

Comment: @BrianCain: I know, but the correct call is still my_class::my_main()

Comment: @user2675345, I'm not sure which part of my example you're referring to as "this".  Yes, you can call `my_class::my_main()` from another class or object's methods.

Comment: @thokra, oh, yes, a typo.  Thanks for catching it -- corrected.

Comment: @Brian Cain So we have replaced my_class::my_method with my_class::my_main? I understand how this may be helpful in limited circumstances...

Comment: @user2675345, indeed. :(  I was offering the most helpful solution I could within the bounds of the question.  Another option to consider could be nesting class definitions.

Answer (score 1):

`my_class` is not a namespace, it is a class name (a type). Therefore, you cannot use `using namespace` with `my_class`.

If you want to use `my_member_1` without prefixing the class name, create a global *wrapper* function.

```
void my_member_1() {
    my_class::my_member_1();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you call a static function like this :

```
my_class::my_member();
```

You are refering to the class definition to find the static function. A static function will be the same for every instance of your class. You cannot access the static function either by simply calling the function name, or by creating an instance of the class to call the static function.

If you want to call directly the static function without writing down the class definition, you could do something like :

```
#define my_member_1 my_class::my_member_1()
#define my_member_2 my_class::my_member_2()
...
```

After that you could simply call my_member_1 to execute your static function, but that could get confusing on a large scale program. My advice is to keep using the class definition so you know exactly what function you are calling.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is I have many members, not that I am referencing the same member many times.